# "Comfort is more important to her"

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "to" or "for" in this sentence and does "comfort" sound natural?

"She always asks you to call in advance if you want to visit her and says that her comfort is more important to/for her. She hates it when people come to her place without a warning."

Comment: Either “to” or “for” could be acceptable but only after you tell us what the “more” is doing in that sentence? What thing is more important than what other thing?  Everything after the “and” in that sentence seems to be random words that have been glued on a good sentence without a clear reason.

Comment: I am describing someone who isn't very social and who would rather spend time reading books than chatting with people. Her comfort is more important to her than chatting with other people.

Comment: So I would suggest ending the sentence at “and” and replacing the second part with a more concise version of what you just said.